# Text in navigation bar doesn't show up

Tags: css

Hello I've made a simple layout where I also display a navigation bar on the top(fixed)
Everything goes fine but the text which I want in the navigation bar doesn't show up.
I've tried to find the solution but couldn't figure it out, thank you very.

HTML CODE:

```
    <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-container"> test test
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <span>test</span> <span>test1</span>
                </tr>
            </tbody>


    </div>          <!-- END banner-container -->
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
    /*========================= BODY =========================*/
body{
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: Hammersmith One;
    margin: 0;
}
span{
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.container{
        height:auto;
        margin-top:-10px;
}

/*========================= HEADER =========================*/
 .banner {
    margin: -10pt auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d9d8d6;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
    position:fixed;
}
.banner-container{
        height:70px;
        width:900px;
        position:center;
        text-align:center;
}
.wrapper{
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        width:900px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin: 0pt auto;
}
/*========================= CONTENT LEFT =========================*/
.content-index{
        width:70%;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        padding-left:20px;
        padding-top:40px;
}

.content-index h1{
        font-size:20px;
        width:98%;
        background-color:#fdfdfd;
        text-align: left;
        color:#000000;
}
.content-index p{
        text-align: left;
        margin: 10px;
        width:98%;
}


.content-index-header{
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.content-index-latest{
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.content-index-latest-cont {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

/*========================= CONTENT RIGHT =========================*/ 
.content-index-right{
        width:25%;
        height:100%;
        float:right;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-top:40px;
}
.content-index-right h1{
        color:#000000;
        font-size:15px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:#fdfdfd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `margin: -10pt auto;` from `.banner`

```
.banner {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d9d8d6;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
    position:fixed;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LLW9a/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `margin` property for banner class.

```
.banner {
   background-color: #D9D8D6;
   border-color: #000000;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;

   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Here the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A5GYb/)

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why are you using table elements without a table?

A couple other things:

- Change banner `margin:-10px auto` to `margin:0 auto`.  Right now it is putting it off the top of the page with the negative vertical margin.
- Remove `position:center` from the container, as this is not an acceptable value.  If you want to center it horizontally, give it a `margin:0 auto` as well.
- If this for a navigation, I would recommend using a UL (list) method instead.
- That is an awful lot of CSS for such a small amount of HTML.  Some of styles you are setting on elements will prove to not be very modular later on in your coding.

Answer (score 0):

margin (-10 auto) => (-10) top and bottom, (auto) left and right

```
.banner {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d9d8d6;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    position:fixed;
}
```